# pg_send_query(): Cannot set connection to blocking mode?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a long-running script that seems to occasionally report the following NOTICE-level error:

> *pg_send_query(): Cannot set connection to blocking mode*

It seems to continue to send queries afterward, but it's unclear if it successfully sends the query that generates the error.

What is this a symptom of?

**Edit:** There are no entries in the postgres log at the time the error occurred, suggesting this is solely a connection error, not something going wrong on postgres' side (e.g. probably not the result of postgres crashing and restarting or something)

**Edit:** As far as I can tell, my INSERT statements are succeeding, one way or another, when this error is triggered.

**Edit:** Looks like this may have been fixed in June 2013: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65015

Comment: I got it in 2024... so not fixed fixed I would say.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is a symptom of `pg_send_query()` not being able to successfully switch the connection back to blocking mode. Looking at the source code in PHPs pgsql.c, you can find:

```
/* {{{ proto bool pg_send_query(resource connection, string query)
   Send asynchronous query */
PHP_FUNCTION(pg_send_query)
{

<... snipped function setup stuff ...>

 if (PQ_SETNONBLOCKING(pgsql, 1)) {
  php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_NOTICE, "Cannot set connection to nonblocking mode");
  RETURN_FALSE;
 }

<... snipped main function execution stuff ...>

 if (PQ_SETNONBLOCKING(pgsql, 0)) {
  php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_NOTICE, "Cannot set connection to blocking mode");
 }
 RETURN_TRUE;
}
```

So the error gets raised at the end of the function, after the main work is done. This fits with your observation that your INSERT statements get executed.

The whole purpose of the two `PQ_SETNONBLOCKING` calls is to put the connection in non blocking mode to allow asynchronous execution and putting it back to the default blocking behaviour afterwards. From the [documentation of PQsetnonblocking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/libpq-async.html): (PQ_SETNONBLOCKING is just an alias defined for that function):

> Sets the nonblocking status of the
>   connection.
>
> ```
> int PQsetnonblocking(PGconn *conn, int arg);
> ```
>
> Sets the state of the connection to nonblocking if arg is 1,
>   or blocking if arg is 0. Returns 0 if
>   OK, -1 if error.
>
> In the nonblocking state, calls to
>   PQsendQuery, PQputline, PQputnbytes,
>   and PQendcopy will not block but
>   instead return an error if they need
>   to be called again.
>
> Note that PQexec does not honor
>   nonblocking mode; if it is called, it
>   will act in blocking fashion anyway.

Looking further at the source of PQsetnonblocking (in PostgeSQLs fe-exec.c), there are two possible reasons why the call could fail:

```
/* PQsetnonblocking:
 * sets the PGconn's database connection non-blocking if the arg is TRUE
 * or makes it non-blocking if the arg is FALSE, this will not protect
 * you from PQexec(), you'll only be safe when using the non-blocking API.
 * Needs to be called only on a connected database connection.
 */
int
PQsetnonblocking(PGconn *conn, int arg)
{
 bool  barg;

 if (!conn || conn->status == CONNECTION_BAD)
  return -1;

 barg = (arg ? TRUE : FALSE);

 /* early out if the socket is already in the state requested */
 if (barg == conn->nonblocking)
  return 0;

 /*
  * to guarantee constancy for flushing/query/result-polling behavior we
  * need to flush the send queue at this point in order to guarantee proper
  * behavior. this is ok because either they are making a transition _from_
  * or _to_ blocking mode, either way we can block them.
  */
 /* if we are going from blocking to non-blocking flush here */
 if (pqFlush(conn))
  return -1;

 conn->nonblocking = barg;

 return 0;
}
```

So either the connection got lost somehow, or pqFlush did not finish successfully, indicating leftover stuff in the connection output buffer.

The first case would be harmless, as your script would certainly notice the lost connection for later calls and react to that (or fail more noticeable).

This leaves the second case, which would mean you have a connection in the non default, non blocking state. I do not know if this could affect later calls that would reuse this connection. If you want to play it safe, you'd close the connection in this case and use a new/other one.

Comment: +1 for identifying the real causes and making practical suggestions of what to do.  Well done!

Comment: I think I've unfortunately been successful in repeating this error with pg_query() combined with pg_pconnect(). Use of pg_send_query() is not required. The pg_query seems to randomly generate this error if previous connection was automatically rolled back when "new" connection is acquired with pg_pconnect(). Problem was visible with PHP 5.3.2 and Postgres 8.4 running on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS x86-64.

Comment: If you hit this problem and are not trying to use `pg_pconnect()` the probable cause is a PHP bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65015

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to use the `pg_send_query()` function for sending asynchronous queries to PostgreSQL.  The purpose of this function is to allow your PHP script to continue executing other code while waiting for PostgreSQL to execute your query and make a result ready.

The example given in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-send-query.php) for `pg_send_query()` suggest that you shouldn't send a query if PostgreSQL is already chewing on another query:

```
if (!pg_connection_busy($dbconn)) {
  pg_send_query($dbconn, "select * from authors; select count(*) from authors;");
}
```

Is there a reason you're using `pg_send_query()` instead of `pg_query()`?  If you can allow your script to block waiting for query execution, I'm guessing (admittedly without having tried it) that you won't see these errors.

Comment: +1 - I assumed that he is doing it asynchronously on purpose, given the 'long-running script' remark, but this would be the obvious solution if that is not the case :)

Comment: One needs to use `pg_send_query()` to be able to correctly query for errors in case query fails. Otherwise you need to use `pg_last_error()` which does not really work that well.

Comment: Beware of bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65015 if you use `pg_send_query()` and talk to remote server. If the query string is too long (in bytes), the `pg_send_query()` will fail because of implementation bug (missing flush before touching counnection). For workaround, install PgBouncer and use pg_connect() to connect to localhost PgBouncer instead of connecting to remote server directly.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently had the same problem, and with the help from Henrik Opels answer realized that PHP does not actually wait for the buffer to flush before setting the connection back to blocking mode.

The 'cannot set connection to blocking mode' is trivially repeatable with large enough queries to fill the send buffer (padding with spaces at the end is enough). With smaller queries I imagine it is dependent on load, and rather intermittent.

if you do actually need asynchronous mode then try the patch at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65015

Comment: One can also install PgBouncer on localhost and use asynchronous mode via it. The PHP bug is triggered only if host is remote.

Comment: I get this issue on localhost connections as well. Do you meant that the issue goes away if we use socket connections?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered same error message with PHP 5.6.9

It occurs when persistent connection made by *pg_pconnect()* is lost and
*pgsql.auto_reset_persistent* is set to *Off*.

Connection might get lost when:

1. PHP Session expires
2. Connection to DB timeouts
3. Webserver / DB server is restarted

You can check PHP.ini for *pgsql.auto_reset_persistent* and set it to *On*.

With *pgsql.auto_reset_persistent* enabled, each time *pg_pconnect()* is being called, connection link is checked, if it is still valid. This requires a little overhead, but fixies error message when conncetion is lost.

Answer (score 3):

I got that error too. I solve my problem by restarting the web server (Apache).

Comment: That worked. Simple enough! :-)

Answer (score 2):

This could occur if you are using **threads** and the connection is being reused.
If is this the case you could use the `PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW` like this:

```
pg_connect("...", PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW)
```

This will force a new database connection resource but be advised: **you could run out of connections clients**, so be carefully using this inside threads so don't forget to use `pg_close()`.